# Keeping Linq to SQL alive when using ViewModels (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lazy-loading, viewmodel

I have recently started using custom ViewModels (For example, CustomerViewModel)

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public IList<Customer> Customers{ get; set; }

    public int ProductId{ get; set; }

     public CustomerViewModel(IList<Customer> customers, int productId)
     {
        this.Customers= customers;
        this.ProductId= productId;
     }

     public CustomerViewModel()
     {
     }
 }
```

... and am now passing them to my view instead of the collections themselves (for example, var Custs =  repository.getAllCusts(id) ) as it seems good practice to do so.

The problem i have encountered is that when using ViewModels; by the time it has got to the the view i have lost the ability to lazy load on customers. I do not believe this was the case before using them.

Is it possible to retain the ability of Lazy Loading while still using ViewModels?
Or do i have to eager load using this method?

Thanks,
Kohan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine that what's stopping your L2S Customer from lazy loading it's properties is that your DataContext is disposed by your repository.

One solution is to not dispose your DataContexts [until the request has been dealt with](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.endrequest(v=VS.71).aspx) - there's quite a few patterns on the internet for dealing with this.

Another option is to not use lazy loading. Since you've got a collection of customers, I'd say that it would be a really good idea to [eagerly load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.loadwith.aspx) whatever it is you need, otherwise you'll be hitting the database once **per customer**

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yes, it's possible to expose the lazy loaded collection on the viewmodel via an `IEnumerable<>` property.  Just expose the getter and have the getter perform the Linq-to-sql query.

I've not had much success with it myself, though, because I prefer to expose collections on viewmodels via a `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<>`.  Using that collection directly must load the data eagerly.  I can imagine creating a collection like the `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<>` that cheats and only does an eager load if the user calls something that requires it (e.g., indexing into the collection), but I've never cared enough to actually implement such a thing.